# JQuery Slider animation only happens for one cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive been attempting to create my own Javascript slider plugin, (I realise there are many out there, but i wanted to treat it as a learning exercise),

an example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/6GTGU/

the problem I'm having is that the animation goes round once, and then stops, Ive tried to examine this to see what i have done wrong but i can't find any reason for it, if anyone can help me i would be very grateful.

HTML

```
    <div id="cjwSlider">
        <div style="background-color: #6495ed"></div>
        <div style="background-color: #62ed43"></div>
        <div style="background-color: #ed5943"></div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    var cjwSlider = $('#cjwSlider');
    var sliderItems = cjwSlider.children('div');

    $(document).ready(function () {
        sliderItems.each(function( index ) {
            $(this).css('z-index', index);
        });

        window.setInterval(function(){

            var maxValue = findMaxZIndex();
            var currentItem = sliderItems.filter(function() {
                return $(this).css('z-index') == maxValue;
            });

            currentItem.addClass("hiddenDiv").delay(1000).queue(function() {
                sliderItems.each(function( index ) {
                    $(this).css('z-index', parseInt($(this).css('z-index')) + 1);
                });

                currentItem.css('z-index', 0);
                currentItem.removeAttr('class');
            });

        }, 4000);


    });

    function findMaxZIndex() {
        var maxValue = undefined;
        $(sliderItems).each(function() {
            var val = $(this).css('z-index');
            val = parseInt(val, 10);
            if (maxValue === undefined || maxValue < val) {
                maxValue = val;
            }
        });
        return maxValue;
    }
```

Comment: For me, it goes like this red -> green -> blue -> red -> green -> STOP. Is this also the sequence you are seeing?

Comment: @Chandranshu That's correct.

Comment: maxValue is always 2. What's the point of that function?

Comment: Yes, that function is pointless currently. Another thing you have got opacity and z-index mixed up. What is your core idea behind the slideshow? Do you want to show slides by changing their z indices or by layering them on top of one-another and setting opacity to zero. As of now, your code stops doing anything when the element with the highest z-index gets the hiddenDiv class.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6GTGU/2/) is a much smaller code which still reproduces your problem. If you can answer my questions, I may be able to help you.

Comment: the intention is that the 1st Div (highest z-value) should change class so that the opacity changes (then you can see item number two) then all items get a z-index increment and item number 1 is then placed at the back of the list (lowest z-value) my intention was the this would just continue looping round, but it stops when it returns to the first one (green)

Comment: the reason for finding max value is that i can then add however many child divs as i like and always return the highest index

Comment: For some reason, I didn't see your comments 9 hours ago today. Will respond to them now.

Comment: @ChrisWarnes why you need that z-indexes at all?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - He is moving the top-most div to the bottom of the stack once it has been rendered transparent.

Comment: @Chandranshu and why that? Still cannot figure out the reason... Might be I need another coffee

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - He probably has something more on his mind - like animating the movement of slides rather than just hiding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working slideshow: http://jsfiddle.net/6GTGU/7/

I've updated the HTML slightly to remove the initialization code from your JS. You may decide to revert that back

**HTML**

```
<div id="cjwSlider">
    <div style="background-color: #6495ed; z-index: 0;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #62ed43; z-index: 1;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #ed5943; z-index: 2;"></div>
</div>
```

I had to remove a lot of JS code to nail down the problem. I think the current JS is all you may need and don't need to go back to your original one:

```
var cjwSlider = $('#cjwSlider');
var sliderItems = cjwSlider.children('div');

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var maxValue = $('#cjwSlider').find('div').length - 1;
        var currentItem = sliderItems.filter(function () {
            return $(this).css('z-index') == maxValue;
        });

        currentItem.addClass("hiddenDiv").delay(1000).queue(function () {
            sliderItems.each(function (index) {
                $(this).css('z-index', parseInt($(this).css('z-index')) + 1);
            });

            currentItem.css('z-index', 0);
            currentItem.removeAttr('class');
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    }, 4000);
});
```

The crux of the problem was the missing call to [`dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) at the end of the function that was queued up. The function executed fine for the first time but then stayed at the head of the queue and prevented execution of functions queued later on. This is why your animation played for one cycle but not after that.

Comment: thanks Chandranshu, this answers my original question and shows me what i did wrong,

Answer (score 2):

[PLUGIN DEMO IN ACTION](http://jsbin.com/eMulEKeW/1/edit)

You said you want a **plugin** so here you go.
**It even stops on mouseenter.** (I personally hate when I cannot stop a gallery by just hovering it.)
<sup>I don't understand the need of `z-index` at all, so you can calmly remove it all from your HTML and don't bother at all.</sup>

```
<div class="cjwFader" id="el1">
    <div style="background: red;">   1 </div>
    <div style="background: green;"> 2 </div>
    <div style="background: gold;">  3 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**
<sub>(the only needed, but you can also make jQ apply the children `position`)</sub>

```
.cjwFader > div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

And finally the **plugin**:

```
(function($){ 
$.fn.cjwFader = function(opts){ 

    // Default Settings
    var S = $.extend({
      fade: 400,
      wait: 2000,
      startAt: 0 
      //, need more? add more.
    },opts);

    return $(this).each(function(){

       var that = $(this),
           child = $('>*',that),
           nOfChildren = child.length,
           sI;

       function animate(){
         child.eq( S.startAt = ++S.startAt % nOfChildren )
              .fadeTo( S.fade,1 )
              .siblings().stop().fadeTo(S.fade,0);
       }     
       function loop(){
         sI=setInterval( animate, S.wait+S.fade );
       }loop();      

       child.hover(function(e){
            return e.type==='mouseenter'? clearInterval(sI) : loop();   
       }).eq(S.startAt).show().siblings().hide();

    });

};
})(jQuery);
```

**Plugin usage:**

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready

  // $('#el1').cjwFader(); // Use default plugin settings

  $('#el1').cjwFader({     // Let's apply some custom stuff
    startAt : 1,
    fade : 1000,
    wait: 700
  });

});
```

Comment: i guess this would be a much better way of aproaching the original problem thanks

Comment: @ChrisWarnes (you're welcome...) Yes, if you plan to reuse it for more elements (read: **plugin**), if you understand jQuery plugins, and if you want to have fun and easily add more functions and options to your plugin. Otherwise... it might turn into a nightmare, and you'll find your self copy-pasting unnecessarily the same code all over the place an see your file turn into a monster, polluting the *global* namespace with variables, functions that might, once you decide to reuse your code in another project... just broke.

Comment: quick question, I know its been a while! do you know why this code might be using up more and more memory? when i do a profile i see the memory usage increasing more and more over time, is there something i can do to fix this? the GC is obviously clearing some things but I don't understand why its not clearing all of it. the cpu usage is fantastic!